# Angular2/angular-cli: Strange errors when trying to build with aot

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-aot

I am trying to build a Angular2 app using the latest version of  angular-cli v1.0.0-rc.2.  This version of angular-cli uses ahead of time compiling by default when building with the --prod switch.  For some unknown reason things always go wrong when I try to compile with --prod.  I can compile when turning off aot with the --aot=false parameter but I would like to build using aot as my app is running a bit slow when deployed without --aot.  My error, package.json and tsconfig.json is below.  Any idea what could be going wrong here and how I can go about fixing it?

## Update 1

It seems like my login component can't resolve the components that get used in the login component's html template.  e.g. I have a Navigation-component HTML tag which triggers the error if it's not commented out.  In all my other modules there doesn't seem to be an issue with aot compilation and the navigation component.  This is very strange and i'm not sure where to go from here/what's going on at all, I am able to generate an aot build when I comment out the navigation error and loader components which are used on my login template...

```
my error:

MProjects\Angular2\angular2-Web\Retail Mobile>ng build --prod
Hash: c8171fe862aa44c60eea
Time: 27901ms
chunk    {0} polyfills.dc48a296046bc6476fcc.bundle.js (polyfills) 231 kB {5} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} main.8307471be6f2dfe65f68.bundle.js (main) 538 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} scripts.a01cf557784923718465.bundle.js (scripts) 226 kB {5} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} styles.7ab5f230646211067b47.bundle.css (styles) 122 bytes {5} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {4} vendor.7d41904f4f70bb9de65b.bundle.js (vendor) 2.46 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {5} inline.991df5c87146e041b5c5.bundle.js (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]

WARNING in ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
601:42-58 "export 'Location' (imported as 'import1') was not found in '../../app/app.module'

WARNING in ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
826:23-39 "export 'Location' (imported as 'import1') was not found in '../../app/app.module'

ERROR in ./src/$$_gendir/app/components/login/login.component.ngfactory.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../loader/loader.component.ngfactory' in 'C:\BRMProjects\Angular2\angular2-Web\Retail Mobile\src\$$_gendir\app\components\login'
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/components/login/login.component.ngfactory.ts 40:0-65
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts

ERROR in ./src/$$_gendir/app/components/login/login.component.ngfactory.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../error/error.component.ngfactory' in 'C:\BRMProjects\Angular2\angular2-Web\Retail Mobile\src\$$_gendir\app\components\login'
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/components/login/login.component.ngfactory.ts 42:0-63
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts

ERROR in ./src/$$_gendir/app/components/goods-received/goods-received.component.ngfactory.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../error/error.component.ngfactory' in 'C:\BRMProjects\Angular2\angular2-Web\Retail Mobile\src\$$_gendir\app\components\goods-received'
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/components/goods-received/goods-received.component.ngfactory.ts 45:0-63
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts

ERROR in ./src/$$_gendir/app/components/login/login.component.ngfactory.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../navigation/navigation.component.ngfactory' in 'C:\BRMProjects\Angular2\angular2-Web\Retail Mobile\src\$$_gendir\app\components\login'
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/components/login/login.component.ngfactory.ts 44:0-73
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts

ERROR in ./src/$$_gendir/app/components/goods-received/goods-received.component.ngfactory.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../navigation/navigation.component.ngfactory' in 'C:\BRMProjects\Angular2\angular2-Web\Retail Mobile\src\$$_gendir\app\components\goods-received'
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/components/goods-received/goods-received.component.ngfactory.ts 47:0-73
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts

ERROR in ./src/$$_gendir/app/Components/loader/loader.component.ngfactory.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './spinner/circle.component.ngfactory' in 'C:\BRMProjects\Angular2\angular2-Web\Retail Mobile\src\$$_gendir\app\Components\loader'
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/Components/loader/loader.component.ngfactory.ts 22:0-65
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/Components/settings/settings.component.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi ./src/main.ts


 my package.json:

 {
  "name": "Retail-Mobile",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "jquery": "3.1.1",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",    
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.0"
  }
}

my tsconfig.json

{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}

my tsconfig.app.json:

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}

my login.component.html:


<div class="container-fluid">
    <navigation-component></navigation-component>
    <div class="row topRow" *ngIf="!busy && !error">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-4">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h1 class="jumbotron">Log in</h1>
            </div>
            <form role="form" [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="login(loginForm.value)">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" [formControl]="loginForm.controls['userName']" placeholder="User Name">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" [formControl]="loginForm.controls['password']" placeholder="password">
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Log In</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <loader [loaderMessage]="loaderMessage" *ngIf="busy"></loader>
    <error [errorMessage]="errorMessage" (dismiss)="dismissError($event)" *ngIf="error"></error>
</div>

    my login.component.ts:

    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';

    import { UserModel } from '../../models/user.model';

    import { RestService } from '../../services/rest.service';
    import { LocalStorageService } from '../../services/local-storage.service';
    import { UserService } from '../../services/user.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-login',
      templateUrl: './login.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
    })
    export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
        loginForm: FormGroup;
        user: UserModel = new UserModel('', '', '');
        busy: boolean = false;
        loaderMessage: string;
        error: boolean = false;
        errorMessage: string;

      constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private restService: RestService, private userService: UserService, private router: Router, private localStorageService: LocalStorageService) { 
        this.loginForm = fb.group({
            'userName':['', Validators.required],
            'password':['', Validators.required]
        });
      }

      login(val: any) {
          this.user.UserName = val.userName;
          this.user.Password = val.password;
          this.user.PasswordHash = '';
          this.loaderMessage = "Logging in";
          this.busy = true;
          this.restService.login(this.user)
          .subscribe(
          (res) => {
              this.busy = false;
              console.log(res);
              if (res.ResponseCode !== 0) {
                  this.errorMessage = res.CustomError;            
                  this.error = true;              
              } else {
                  this.userService.setAuthentication(res.SessionUserID);
                  console.log(res.SessionUserID);
                  this.router.navigate(['home']);
                  this.loginForm.reset();
              }       
          },
          (res) => {
              console.log(res);
              this.errorMessage = "Technical error...";
              this.error = true;                
              this.busy = false;
          });
      }

      dismissError(event: any) {
            this.error = false;
        }

      ngOnInit() {
          this.restService.init('1');
          if (this.userService.isAuthenticated()) {
              this.router.navigate(['home']);
          } 
      }

    }

    my loader.component.html:

    <div class="row loading" >  
            <sk-circle></sk-circle>
            <h4>{{loaderMessage}}</h4>
        </div>

    my loader.component.ts:

    import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'loader',
      templateUrl: './loader.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./loader.component.css']
    })
    export class LoaderComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() loaderMessage: string;

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

    }

    my app.mocule.ts:

    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
    import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { CircleComponent } from './components/loader/spinner/circle.component';
    import {APP_BASE_HREF} from '@angular/common';
    import { StringToDatePipe } from './pipes/string-to-date.pipe';


    import { ProductComponent } from './Components/product/product.component';

    import { CheckBarcodesComponent } from './Components/check-barcodes/check-barcodes.component';
    import { HomeComponent } from './Components/home/home.component';
    import { NavigationComponent } from './Components/navigation/navigation.component';
    import { SettingsComponent } from './Components/settings/settings.component';
    import { StockTransactionItemComponent } from './Components/stock-transaction-item/stock-transaction-item.component';
    import { StockTakeComponent } from './Components/stock-take/stock-take.component';
    import { LoaderComponent } from './Components/loader/loader.component';
    import { ErrorComponent } from './Components/error/error.component';
    import { GoodsReceivedComponent } from './components/goods-received/goods-received.component';
    import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';

    import { RestService } from './services/rest.service';
    import { LocalStorageService } from './services/local-storage.service';
    import { UserService } from './services/user.service';

    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';
    import { StatusComponent } from './Components/status/status.component';



    @NgModule({
        declarations: [
            AppComponent,
            ProductComponent,
            CheckBarcodesComponent,
            HomeComponent,
            NavigationComponent,
            SettingsComponent,
            StockTransactionItemComponent,
            StockTakeComponent,
            CircleComponent,
            LoaderComponent,
            GoodsReceivedComponent,
            ErrorComponent,
            StatusComponent,
            LoginComponent,
            StringToDatePipe    
        ],
        imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            FormsModule,
            ReactiveFormsModule,
            HttpModule,
            AppRoutingModule
        ],
        providers: [
            RestService,
            LocalStorageService,
            UserService,
            Location,
            //{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
            { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/brmservices/webenquiry/ng2/dist/' }
        ],
        bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html

Comment: Can you share your code? do you import components or services from npm packages? Do you use 'export default' somewhere?

Comment: @Ahmed Musallam The nly components I import from npm are all required angular components e.g. Component OnInit etc.  And I don't use export default anywhere...  My app is probably too big to post here.  Anything in particular that I can post/look at?

Comment: It seems like the components it's complaining about in the errors are all components that are used in other components e.g. my navigation component, loader component and error component...

Comment: @user2094257 it's difficult to help without your code, can we look at your login and loader component as well as your app module?

Comment: @Ahmed Musallam  I added my login and loader components as well as app.module.ts.  Thanks for taking a look

Comment: @user2094257 this seems like a bug in the angular-cli. I'd say do the following:
1. remove angular cli globally: npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
2. Remove your app node_modules folder.
3. install angular cli back globally. npm install -g @angular/cli@1.0.0-rc.2
4. in your app, run npm install (to rebuild the node_modules folder)

you may also want to try upgrading to the latest angular cli 1.0.0